Turn off the beep caused by "edited outside of the Wolfram System"
Sometimes I use vscode/ecplise to batch-replace code across multiple notebooks, and the beep becomes quite annoying. Is there a way to disable it? I searched the preference but did not find relevant options.


There is a workaround.
This beep will disappear after opening and saving the notebook. So within Mathematica we can use the following method:
Firstly we use FileNames["*.nb",dir,Infinity] to get the notebook paths, then feed them into this function for batch-open/save
batchOpenSaveNotebook[nbList_List,pause_:0.5] :=
    Module[ {nb,nbobj,counter = 0},
        Monitor[
            Do[
                counter = counter+1;
                nbobj = NotebookOpen[nb];
                Pause[pause];
                NotebookSave[nbobj];
                Pause[pause];
                NotebookClose[nbobj],
                {nb,nbList}
            ],
            ProgressIndicator[counter,{0,Length@nbList}]
        ]
    ];

Make sure you have saved other notebooks, since if pause is too small the frontend may get stuck.
